# CSS parent background color is not filling child containers

Tags: html, css

I am trying set the background color of the navbar, however the color doesn't seem to extend to the child container. What am I missing? I am using a display flexbox so I can evenly distribute the content of the navbar. I think it has something to do with the Flex property, but I couldn't find anything helpful online. Please help!

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: orangered;
}

li, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; /*evenly distribute flex box */
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 5%;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.nav_links_left {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav_links_left li{
    display: inline-block;  /* make it side by side */
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav_links_left li a{
    transition: all 0.3s  ease 0s;  /* Make a tags move */
}

.nav_links_left li a:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links_left">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <img class="logo" src="images/RhymeMaster_Logo.png" alt="logo">
        <nav>
            <ul  class="nav_links_left">
                <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Remove `background-color: orangered;` from `* {  background-color: orangered; }`.

Comment: Or, if you want to keep `* {  background-color: orangered; }`, just add `.nav_links_left li{ background-color: inherit }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` selects any element on the page and will apply `orangered` as a `background-color` to all elements, which don't overwirte the `background` property themselfes.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* background-color: orangered; */
}
```

If you want to keep `orangered` as your background-color, add:

```
body {
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, totally missed this. Thanks!

Comment: @mpurkaye. All fine. Glad I could help!